# How do I get out of the showUsage() method in the main method?

Tags: java

Every time I run my program, it goes straight into the showUsage method in the if statement. Why is that? How can I continue with the program without getting stuck in the showUsage method? I want to be able to run this program so I can input the data into txt file but unfortunately, I'm getting stuck in the showUsage() method.

```
public class DataGenerator 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        if ( args.length != 1)
       {
           showUsage();
           System.exit(0);
       }


       String target = args[0];  
       switch (target)
       {
          case "trans" :
             generateTransactionRecords();
             break; 
          case "master" :
             generateAccountRecords(); 
             break;
          default : 
              showUsage();     
       }



    }

    private static void showUsage()
    {
    System.out.println("Usage: DataGenerator trans|master");
    System.out.println(" trans to generate trans.txt representing transcations data");
    System.out.println(" master to generate oldmast.txt representing account recorddata");      
    }

    /**
     * In a loop, prompts the user to enter transaction record one at time. 
     * Figure out a way to enable user to exit the loop
     * Write out all the transaction records in a text file called trans.txt  
     * 
     */
    private static void generateTransactionRecords()
    {
        System.out.println("generateTransactionRecords() called");
        Scanner keyboard= new Scanner (System.in);
        String [] args = new String [1];
        args[0] = "trans.txt";
        //String fileName = arg[0];//"trans.txt";
        //String fileName = "";
        PrintWriter outputStream = null;

        try
        {
        outputStream = new PrintWriter(args[0]);//fileName);

        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error opening the file" + args[0]);
            System.exit(0);
        }

        outputStream.println ("Transaction file" + "        " + "Transaction");
        outputStream.println ("account number" +   "        " + "    amount");
        boolean keepGoing = true;
        while (keepGoing)
        {

            System.out.println("What is the account number?");
            int accountNum = keyboard.nextInt();
            System.out.println("What is the transaction amount?");
            double TransAction = keyboard.nextDouble();
            outputStream.println(accountNum + "                        " + TransAction);

            System.out.println("Do you want to enter more information?");
            String answer;
            answer = keyboard.next();
            if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))
            {
                keepGoing = false;
            }


        }
        outputStream.close();       
    }


    /**
     * In a loop, prompts the user to enter customer account record one at time. 
     * Figure out a way to enable user to exit the loop
     * Write out all the account records in a text file called oldmast.txt  
     * 
     */
    private static void generateAccountRecords()
    {
        System.out.println("generateAccountRecords() called");
        Scanner keyboard= new Scanner (System.in);

        String [] args = new String [1];
        args[0] = "trans.txt";
        PrintWriter outputStream = null;

        try
        {
        outputStream = new PrintWriter(args[0]);

        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error opening the file" + args[0]);
            System.exit(0);
        }

        outputStream.println ("Master file");
        outputStream.println  ("account number" +   "       Name" + "      Balance");
        boolean keepGoing = true;
        while (keepGoing)
        {
            System.out.println("What is the account number?");
            int accountNum = keyboard.nextInt();
            System.out.println("What is the name?");
            String name = keyboard.nextLine();
            System.out.println("What is the name?");
            int Balance = keyboard.nextInt();
            outputStream.println(accountNum +      "                   " +name+"          " +        Balance);

            System.out.println("Do you want to enter more information?");
            String answer;
            answer = keyboard.nextLine();
            if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))
            {
                keepGoing = false;
            }


        }
        outputStream.close();
}


}
```

Comment: Dump the args array to System.out to verify you are passing parameters

Comment: Do you supply a run-time argument?

Comment: How are you running your java class, I mean, the command line?

Comment: This isnt a question and advice site. Mark one of the many questions as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the program as:

```
java DataGenerator someArgument
```

Coming back to your code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
   // here you are checking for the length of the args array not equal to 1
   // If its not equal to one then, enter the if block
   // To avoid the if block, you need to run the program with exactly 1
   // command line argument
   if ( args.length != 1)
   {
       showUsage();
       System.exit(0);
   }
 ...............

}
```

`args` is an array of `String` which are called [Command line arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html). So, if you run your program from command line as `java DataGenerator someX someY`, then `args` will contain `[someX,someY]` and `args.length` will be 2.

Answer (score 1):

If you are entering the `showUsage` method, it means you haven't supplied *exactly* one argument.

Try printing a copy of the arguments to see what was supplied:

```
for (String s : args) {
  System.out.println(s);
}
```

On the command line, you need to run `java DataGenerator foo` (where `foo` is your argument). If you are using an IDE, check the help to understand how to specify runtime arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go ahead and guess it's because you aren't passing any command line arguments when you run the program. `String[] args` is filled with the command line arguments you pass to the program at runtime.

If there aren't any arguments the `if` statement will be evaluated to `true` and `showUsage()` will run followed by `System.exit(0)` which exits the program.